# How to store java.util.ArrayList in Postgresql using Spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, arraylist, batch-updates

I am trying to do a batch-insert of a collection of beans. One of the properties of the bean is an ArrayList. The batch update fails with the exception:

```
 Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

I don't know which Postgresql data type to use for the ArrayList to be compatible. Is there a way I can do the batch update of the beans without changing the data type of its properties?

---

The Bean:

```
    import java.util.List;

    public class SomeBean {
        private int id;
        private List<String> names;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "SomeBean [id=" + id + ", names=" + names + "]";
        }
        //Setters and getters
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE arraylistexample
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  names character varying[]
)
```

Method to insert the data:

```
    public void insert(List<SomeBean> beans){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO ARRAYLISTEXAMPLE (NAMES) VALUES (:names)";

        SqlParameterSource[] data = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(beans.toArray());
        pgTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, data);
    }
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO ARRAYLISTEXAMPLE (NAMES) VALUES (?, ?)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:603)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:884)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:303)
    at some.package.dao.GenericDao.insert(GenericDao.java:45)
    at some.package.runner.FileLogicTester.storingArrayListInDb(FileLogicTester.java:220)
    at some.package.runner.FileLogicTester.main(FileLogicTester.java:86)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1801)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gStatement.setObject(AbstractJdbc3gStatement.java:37)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Statement.setObject(AbstractJdbc4Statement.java:46)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setObject(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchUpdateUtils.setStatementParameters(BatchUpdateUtils.java:63)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.access$000(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:32)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils$1.setValues(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:893)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:884)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    ... 7 more
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem.
[Here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/50344D58.9010401@ringerc.id.au) people discussed about that.
Looks like it's the fault of the JDBC driver or PostgeSQL itself, so you can't just pass an array to the DB. As a workaround I had to manually create SQL (I had integer values, so didn't care about sql injections; you may want to prepare dynamically `SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (?,?,?)` first and then process the statement).

```
private static final String SQL_FIND_GOAL = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID IN (:ids)";

public List<MyGoal> getAllMyGoals(Set<Integer> ids) {
// Work around of issue.
int i=0;
String mockInStatement = "";
for (int type: ids){
  if (i < ids.size()-1){
    mockInStatement = mockInStatement + type + ",";
  }
  else {
    mockInStatement = mockInStatement + type;
  }
  i++;
}
String refinedSQL = SQL_FIND_GOAL.replace(":ids",mockInStatement);

List<MyGoal> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
    refinedSQL, 
    new RowMapper<MyGoal>() {
      @Override
      public MyGoal mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        MyGoal myGoal = new MyGoal();
        myGoal.setCode(rowNum);
        myGoal.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        return myGoal;
      }
    });
return result;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a typed Java array and it should work:

```java
String insertSql = "INSERT INTO my_table(my_array) VALUES(?)";
jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql,myArrayList.toArray(new String[myArrayList.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the data type for PGSQL is incorrect, refer
[this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-TABLE)

> character varying(n)  varchar(n)  variable-length character string

What you are probably looking for is 
[PGSQL Arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not the OP's issue, but I ran into this error when accidentally using `jdbcTemplate.update` instead of `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

Consider also converting the ArrayList to Array.

```
arrayList.toArray();
```